# How to split an already split array ruby

Tags: ruby

I have this function in Ruby

```
def translate word  
  vowels=["a","e","I","O","U"]  
  i=1.to_i
  sentense=word.split(" ").to_a     
  puts sentense if sentense.length >=1
  sentense.split("")        
  puts sentense     
end
```

I have this phrase "this is a test phrase " and at first I want to create an array that looks like:

```
["this","is","a", "test", "phrase"]
```

Then I want to create another array  it to look like:
`[["t","h","i","s"],["i","s"],["a"],["t","e","s","t"],["p","h","r","a","s","e"]`.

I tried

```
sentense=word.split(" ").to_a
new_array=sentense.split("").to_a
```

but it didn't work

Comment: "but it didn't work" - of course. You'll need to call `split` on individual elements.

Comment: `split` always returns an array, the `to_a` is superfluous.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`String#split`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-split), [`Enumerable#map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) and [`String#chars`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-chars):

```
p "this is a test phrase".split.map(&:chars)
# => [["t", "h", "i", "s"], ["i", "s"], ["a"], ["t", "e", "s", "t"], ["p", "h", "r", "a", "s", "e"]]
```

`string.split(' ')` could be written as `string.split`, so you can omit passing the whitespace in parenthesis.

And this also gives you an array, there's no need to use `to_a`, you'll have an array like `["this", "is", "a", "test", "phrase"]`, so you can use map to get a new array and for each element inside an array of its characters by using `.split('')` or `.chars`.

Comment: You don't mention `map` in your explanation, although it's the essential part.

Comment: Sorry, now yes @Stefan.

Comment: I did this way because i the phrase will change but i get an undefined method for split def translate word
 
 sentense=word.split
 sentense.split.map(&:chars)
  puts split
 end
 translate("I have this phrase")

Comment: You're using split as a variable, but you haven't defined it @CharalambosPouroutides. And the second split isn't needed if you've initialized sentences as word.split, try `def translate word; sentense = word.split; sentense.map(&:chars); end; p translate("I have this phrase")`.

Comment: Now it works Thank you Sebastian                                                              def translate word;
  sentense = word.split;
  sentense.map(&:chars);
  end;
  p translate("I have this phrase")

Comment: @CharalambosPouroutides you can omit the temporary variable and simply write `word.split.map(&:chars)`

Answer (score 1):

```
def chop_up(str)
  str.strip.each_char.with_object([[]]) { |c,a| c == ' ' ? (a << []) : a.last << c }
end

chop_up "fee fi fo fum"
  #=> [["f", "e", "e"], ["f", "i"], ["f", "o"], ["f", "u", "m"]]
chop_up " fee fi fo fum "
  #=> [["f", "e", "e"], ["f", "i"], ["f", "o"], ["f", "u", "m"]]
chop_up "feefifofum "
  #=> [["f", "e", "e", "f", "i", "f", "o", "f", "u", "m"]]
chop_up ""
  #=> [[]]
```

Comment: I would use @Sebastián's answer, but thought mine might be of interest.